# в textarea выводятся \n вместо переноса

Tags: textarea

Здравствуйте!
Есть на станице `textarea` используемый как блокнот куда пишу всякие заметки

```
первая строка
вторая строка

третья строка
```

после сохранения получается

```
первая строка\nвторая строка\n\nтретья строка
```

так же в базе данных отображается(тип поля TEXT).

Вот как записываю и извлекаю данные:

```
function change_note ()
{
$note = (string)$this->request['note'];
bb_update(Array('note' => DB()->escape($note),));
$this->response['html'] = 'сохраненo';
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ajax.change_note = function() {
    ajax.exec({
    action : 'change_note',
    note : $('#note').val()
    });
    };
    ajax.callback.change_note = function(data){
    $('#res_note').html(data.html);
    }
    </script>
    <table><tr>
    <th colspan="2"><h3>NOTE</h3></th>
    </tr><tr><td>
    <textarea rows=15 cols=150 id="note" name="note">{NOTE}</textarea>
    <br><input type="button" value="SAVE" onclick="ajax.change_note();">
    <div id="res_note"></div>
    </td>
    </tr></table>
```

`$template->assign_vars(array("NOTE" => nl2br($note)));`

Сохраненные данные отображаю не в отдельном блоке, а в том же `textarea`.

Интересно что после очередного сохранения к сучествующей `\n` добавляется еще одна `\`

SAVE

`первая строка\\nвторая строка\\n\\nтретья строка\nчетвертая`

SAVE

`первая строка\\\\nвторая строка\\\\n\\\\nтретья строка\\nчетвертая\nпятая`

Что нужно сделать чтобы из базы результат без `\n` отображались(как обычный перенос) и почему лишняя `\` появляется после очередного сохранения записки?

Comment: escape пытается обезопасить служебный символ "\" поставив перед ним "\". Так получается "\\". При следующем сохранении escape экранирует два небезопасных символа "\\" из чего получается "\\\\"

Comment: Что вместо эскапе использовать?

Comment: тут надо смотреть видимо данные в change-note уже попадают экранированными, где экранируются еще раз

Comment: Пробовал заменять \n прегреплэйсом на <br>. Меняет, но опять же не переносит.  Но проблема с \ остается, если эта слэшь присутствует в тексте, то при каждом сохранении текста появляется дополнительная \

Comment: bb_update - это что? и вообще бэкэндом что служит? PHP? Фреймворк какой-то или это собственные скрипты? Похоже, что функция bb_update не нуждается в экранировании и делает экранирование где-то внутри себя. Попробуйте вообще без escape

Comment: Бб_упдэйт это поле в бд куда сохраняется текст из textarea. В базу все нормально сохраняет, проблема с выводом содержимого...

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> nl2br($note)
> ```

Предлагаю убрать это.

Comment: Что с nl2br() , что без неё отображается одинаково, пробывал уже убирать

Comment: @D-side ок, учту